# How to gradually update images in a table (part II)

Tags: css, image

In answer to my last question of "How to gradually update images in a table", A Haworth suggested using CSS animations and supplied the code for it, which worked, perfectly. Except all the images on the page were either stacked on each other or were just displayed separately but did not rotate (image-wise)

```css
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px 20px;
}

table,
table td;

}
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@keyframes rotateimgs {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  33.33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  66.66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
td {
  position: relative;
  --interval: 5s;
  /* set this to what you want the fade-in time to be */
}
.rotate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: rotateimgs;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--interval) * 3);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}
img .rotate:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  position: relative;
}
img .rotate:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: var(--interval);
}
img .rotate:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--interval)*2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <table class="center" style="max-width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142245/CSS8.png" />
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142309/php7.png" />
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142254/html9.png" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142245/CSS8.png" />
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142309/php7.png" />
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142254/html9.png" />
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142245/CSS8.png" />
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142309/php7.png" />
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142254/html9.png" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142245/CSS8.png" />
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142309/php7.png" />
        <img class="rotate" src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142254/html9.png" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I needed to subclass the rotation section so some images on the page, like logos, would not cycle through the rotation. That worked, except all the images are on top of each other. My goal is, if possible, one table, two columns, two rows, four rotating images in all. BUT AT THE SAME TIME display images which do not have those "rotate" qualities.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!
RON

Comment: It would be useful if you had a visual example of how you want the final result to look like.

Comment: When image and css then jsfiddle if want more help.